# How to create high res PDF of multiple images from Lightroom or Photoshop on a Mac?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, software, os-x

I have Photoshop and LightRoom and I have 10 photos that I want to submit for a magazine.  The guideline says

```
Please submit your webitorial as a high res PDF including all images, wardrobe, and team credits
```

I am on Mac and don't know photoshop much either, How do we create one PDF of all images? and also one page of text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions look to some part quite specific for the publication.

Do they just want the complete set of pictures in a PDF, or is there more layout involved?

Also, the instructions are not complete, as they should at least specify the color profile to be used, or they should refer to color settings. At the very, very least, they should say whether to submit the images as RGB (preferable), or CMYK (cause for issues).

That said, you'd better use Photoshop for exporting as PDF, because Photoshop uses the Adobe library for PDF creation, which is far superior than what Apple uses in Preview.app.

If they want layout, they should provide templates, or at least guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mac OS X's built-in Preview application to combine PDFs into a single PDF file. Also built-in to Mac OS X is the ability to export any file as PDF (either in the **File > Export As...** menu if available, or in the **Print to PDF** exporter in the Print dialog).

1. For each of the 10 photos that you want to submit, in Lightroom, Print them. The system's **Print** dialog will open. In the bottom left of the **Print** dialog, select **Save as PDF...** in the drop-down. Select the folder to save the images as PDFs.
2. Open the **Finder** in the folder where the exported PDFs are located, and select the 10 PDF files, then in the menu bar select **File > Open With > Preview**.

   [image]
3. In Preview, in the upper left of the toolbar, click the **View Menu**  button, **> Thumbnails**. You can drag the thumbnails of each of the PDFs into one of the PDFs to create a combined PDF file containing all of your images.

Comment: With all due respect but this workflow is not really suitable for serious publishing.

Comment: @MaxWyss agreed. But the OP didn't mention publishing. It sounded like the requirement was for a single PDF file as a container for the image submission. I assume the magazine would do layout.